# I want to setup a Multi-node OpenStack with microStack but it keep failing, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: openstack

I want to setup a Multi-node OpenStack with microStack but it keep failing.

I am following this : https://ubuntu.com/openstack/install#multi-node-deployment

For the control node i do :

```
sudo microstack.init
Do you want to setup clustering? (yes/no) [default=yes] > yes
2020-04-05 23:10:37,251 - microstack_init - INFO - Configuring clustering ...
What is this machines' role? (control/compute) > control
Please enter a cluster password > 
Please re-enter password > 
Please enter the ip address of the control node [default=192.168.0.31] > 192.168.0.31
.
.
2020-04-05 23:14:14,252 - microstack_init - INFO - Complete. Marked microstack as initialized!
```

This part is ok, but a problem is occurring when i want to add a compute node.
So i do this :

```
multipass exec microstack-vm -- sudo microstack.init
Do you want to setup clustering? (yes/no) [default=no] > yes
2020-04-05 23:13:40,657 - microstack_init - INFO - Configuring clustering ...
What is this machines' role? (control/compute) > compute
Please enter a cluster password >
Please re-enter password >
Please enter the ip address of the control node [default=192.168.0.31] > 192.168.0.31
Please enter the ip address of this node [default=192.168.64.2] > 192.168.64.2
2020-04-05 23:16:37,680 - microstack_init - INFO - I am a compute node.
```

And here is the error stack : https://pastebin.com/unYw5LE2

I can see that the program fails to establish the connection between the two nodes, but i can't see why.

The first machine is on ubuntu  18.04.4 LTS, the second is on osx 10.14.6 (Mojave), both have the required configuration (or more), and they are on the same network (and like 50cm apart ).

Am i missing something ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am working on getting experience on microstack as we speak....so i am not sure.
It looks like your not specifying a cluster password or you are specifying an empty password which seemed fine at first but whenever you connect if fails. See line 14/15 of your pastebin